# Spring injection ResourceLoader null grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I have the below class which is trying to inject ResourceLoader in a service class which is in groovy.

```
    public class PgpEncryptionService implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PgpEncryptionService.name)
    static transactional = false

    static {
        // init the security provider
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
    }

    ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    public PgpEncryptionService() {

    }
}
```

I have read in the blog that adding a default constructor would avoid the NullPointerException:
http://refaktor.blogspot.sg/2012/10/inconsistent-dependency-injection-to.html?showComment=1447150210108#c8899018499945470182

But still the ResourceLoader is null and I get a NullPointerException